# "Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path channels problem

Tags: django

I got this error: `ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)`

Here is my routing.py:

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.urls import path

from messanger.contacts.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                    path('user-notification', ChatConsumer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
})
```

When i remove this line of code, runserver work: `from messanger.contacts.consumers import ChatConsumer`

But i don't understand what's wrong with my consumers file in contacts app:

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):

    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": event["text"],
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` file add:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'yourappname.asgi.application'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by going  in the asgi.py file and import get_asgi_application() which act as tradition http request fallback Like so  in asgi.py :

```
mport os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
# Initialize Django ASGI application early to ensure the AppRegistry
# is populated before importing code that may import ORM models.
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from chat.consumers import AdminChatConsumer, PublicChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                path("chat/admin/", AdminChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                path("chat/", PublicChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your `settings.py` file : 
 
`ASGI_APPLICATION = 'yourappname.routing.application'`
 
and that is because ASGI_APPLICATION is looking for `application = ...` in your files. And also there could be a potentional problem with your not adding `ChatConsumer.as_asgi()` in your path which will instantiate a new consumer instance for each connection.